# How to mask url from siteA.com to retreive data from siteB.com/page1.aspx?id=1234 - ( IIS - URLrewrite - ARR)

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module, arr

Let say the situation is

- User type "http://siteA.com" without pagename or querystring in the browser's address bar then click "Go"
- IIS receives the request and redirect it to "https://siteB.com/page1.aspx?id=1234"
- IIS receives the response from "https://siteB.com/page1.aspx?id=1234"
- IIS rewrites the url to "http://siteA.com/home" so users will see this url in their address bars.
- At this state, any links on "http://siteA.com/home" must have http://siteA.com as domain name in URLs. Users should see the links like below links

http://siteA.com/page2.aspx
http://siteA.com/page3.aspx

page1.aspx, page2.aspx, and page3.aspx are actually hosted on https://siteB.com

How many rewrite rules do I need? How to write those? How to set up ARR? Any working examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You asked a lot of questions at once, but in summary, you don’t know much about URL rewriting. So I suggest you take a look at the Microsoft documentation: [URL Rewrite Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-video-walkthrough)